# SSHAuthenticationExcetion :No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication

Tags: vb.net, winforms, unix, ssh

I'm trying to connect on a server in vb.net win forms. I put a button and a text area to receive the data. But I'm unable to connect on the server. The server is open because i can ping it.

```
Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
    Dim PasswordConnection = New PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username", "pass")
    Dim KeyboardInteractive = New KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod("username")
    Dim ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo("server.com", 22, "username", PasswordConnection, KeyboardInteractive)

    Using client As New SshClient(ConnectionInfo)
        client.Connect()

        Dim cmd As SshCommand
        Dim result As String
        Dim result2 As String

        cmd = client.CreateCommand("who")
        cmd.CommandTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        result = cmd.Execute
        result2 = cmd.Error
        MemoEdit1.Text = cmd.ExitStatus

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(result2) Then
            MemoEdit1.Text = result2
        End If

        MemoEdit1.Text = result

        client.Disconnect()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Am I doing something wrong?
The program stuck directly on the "client.Connect()". As you can see im trying to connect on the event click of SimpleButton1

Comment: Does the SSH server allow keyboard/password authentication?

Comment: I ussualy use this code before but having the same problem: Using client As New SshClient("server.com", 22, "username", "pass")

Comment: I dont know if the server allor that type of authentication...

Comment: you can ping all you like.  the question is, can you telnet to port 22?

Comment: Normally `No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication` is used by an SSH server when the server does not allow authentication by the offered methods by the client. The SSH server could only allow public key authentication, or some form of two factor authentication in turn preventing password authentication. Download an SSH client like [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and try to connect to the server and see what the result is.

Comment: you was right guys i cannot connect using telnet and putty cause the person who asked me to do this application send me the wrong server. I'm sorry to waste your times guys. And Steven if you could write your last comment like an answer I'll could close this question. With the good server everything work,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally `No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication is used` is returned from an SSH server when the server does not allow authentication by the offered methods by the client.

The SSH server could only allow public key authentication, or some form of two factor authentication in turn preventing password authentication. Download an SSH client like [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and try to connect to the server directly and see what the result is.

Comment: you are i cannot connect using telnet and putty cause the person who asked me to do this application send me the wrong server. With the good server everything work