# Renci.Ssh Additional information: No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, ssh, sftp

Hi everyone I must connect to a SFTP server witch renci.ssh... Untill some days ago everything worked, now no-more... I do not understan why... I have seen this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456903/sshauthenticationexcetion-no-suitable-authentication-method-found-to-complete-a) and this [one](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/361314).. but no success... 
here the code I am using:

```
 using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(
                new PasswordConnectionInfo(
                    base.Uri.Host, this._portNumber,
                    base.Credential.UserName,
                    base.Credential.Password))
               )
        {
            client.Connect();

            ...

            client.Disconnect();
        }
```

I am using WinSCP to test if server is ok... ant server seems ok... What could be happened? 
Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Find the problem... I forgot the password :( How can I change or find it again?

Comment: I don't know what happened.. the password was ok, but the server was like blocked... I had had to connect via cygWin and then via my project in VS... everything works now...